# Cannot open client webcam - Flasksocketio

Tags: flask, live-streaming, flask-socketio

app.py:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    msg = ""
    if (
        request.method == "POST"
        and "username" in request.form
        and "password" in request.form
    ):

        username = request.form["username"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s AND password = %s",
            (
                username,
                password,
            ),
        )
        account = cursor.fetchone()

        if account:
            session["loggedin"] = True
            session["id"] = account["id"]
            session["username"] = account["username"]
            msg = "Logged in successfully"
            return render_template("index.html", msg=msg)

        else:
            msg = "Incorrect username / password !"
    return render_template("login.html", msg=msg)


@socketio.on("image")
def image(data_image):
    sbuf = StringIO()
    sbuf.write(data_image)

    # decode and convert into image
    b = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data_image))
    pimg = Image.open(b)

    ## converting RGB to BGR, as opencv standards
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pimg), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    # Process the image frame
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=700)
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    imgencode = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)[1]

    # base64 encode
    stringData = base64.b64encode(imgencode).decode("utf-8")
    b64_src = "data:image/jpg;base64,"
    stringData = b64_src + stringData

    # emit the frame back
    emit("response_back", stringData)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js"
        integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <canvas id="canvasOutput"></canvas>
        <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></video>
    </div>

    <div class='video'>
        <img id="image">
    </div>

    <script>
        var socket = io('http://localhost:5000/login');

        socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log("Connected...!", socket.connected)
        });

        const video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

        video.width = 500;
        video.height = 375;;

        if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.play();
                })
                .catch(function (err0r) {
                    console.log(err0r)
                    console.log("Something went wrong!");
                });
        }

        let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);
        let src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
        let dst = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC1);



        const FPS = 22;

        setInterval(() => {
            cap.read(src);

            var type = "image/png"
            var data = document.getElementById("canvasOutput").toDataURL(type);
            data = data.replace('data:' + type + ';base64,', ''); //split off junk at the beginning

            socket.emit('image', data);
        }, 10000 / FPS);


        socket.on('response_back', function (image) {
            const image_id = document.getElementById('image');
            image_id.src = image;
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Error on the console:

```
DOMException: Could not start video source
```

I have a flask web app where when a user logs in, the web camera opens to render a live video stream on the web app. but it throws an error that it cannot open the camera and start a video stream, where am I doing wrong how can I access the camera and display in when user logs in.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Flask, Flask-SocketIO or even Python. I suggest you use more appropriate tags for JavaScript, Media Capture API, etc.